# SoundCloud's connect with Facebook not working in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm trying to integrate my iOS app with SoundCloud. I've registered an app at "http://soundcloud.com/you/apps" and got the app ID and secret key in order to compose the auth URL:

"https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=da3beb496ca5bd92e2ae39a4bf775cca&redirect_uri=rocksteady://oauth2&response_type=code"

I simply made a UIWebView load a request with that very url. After pushing the "Connect with Facebook" button app redirected to the facebook login page. After logging in the Facebook I got redirected back to SoundCloud and finally my callback uri was called and I got my access token. All worked just fine on 15th of March 2012.

Today I've launched the project and got the following oAuth exception from Facebook:

```
{
   "error":{
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191}
}
```

I've found out that now app redirects to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?x=82&y=15 but on the 15th of March the url was [different](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?display=touch&redirect_uri=https://soundcloud.com/connect/via/facebook/returning&state=eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJkYTNiZWI0OTZjYTViZDkyZTJhZTM5YTRiZjc3NWNjYSIsInJlZGlyZWN0X3VyaSI6InJvY2tzdGVhZHk6Ly9vYXV0aDIiLCJyZXNwb25zZV90eXBlIjoiY29kZSIsInBvcHVwIjpmYWxzZX0=&scope=publish_actions,email,user_birthday,offline_access&client_id=19507961798) and contained all the parameters required to redirect back to SoundCloud after logging in.

The authorization process using desctop computer works just fine (checked using Safari & Chrome).

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this fixed? Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for posting a few links as strings. Not enough mana to post more than two links for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hej,

Robb here from SoundCloud. This is an issue on our end and we are working on a fix right now.
I'll update this post when we have deployed a fix.

**Update:** Fixed as of Wed Mar 21 16:07:43 UTC 2012

Comment: Robb, thanks a ton! Nice job! BTW it's a really cool service you got there!

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure if you are notified by my post below, so I just leave a comment here.