# SoundCloud's Facebook authentication not working

Tags: facebook, authentication, soundcloud

I still experience exactly the bug described here: [SoundCloud's connect with Facebook not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804279/soundclouds-connect-with-facebook-not-working-in-ios).

My app is built in Adobe AIR. The app's name is CloudDeck (clouddeck.net).

The temporary solution is that may help you narrow down the issue: If the user logs in to Facebook to share a link with the [f] icon on the top (so not using SoundCloud's Facebook connect), then SoundCloud's Facebook connect will work. I use for that functionality the "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" URL.

The screenshot above is where SoundCloud Facebook connect redirects[image]

Comment: This bug still isn't resolved :(

Comment: Guys, this issue is still ON!